# Changing CSS properties from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

[image: I want to change the padding and top, width to 0 using Javascript]

Not able to do that.

Been trying things like:

```
 document.getElementById("sharebar").innerHTML="";  //This works
 alert(document.getElementById("sharebar").toString());
document.getElementById("sharebar").setAttribute("width", "0px"); //To remove formatting but this doesnt
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("sharebar").setAttribute("style", "width:0px;");
```

Comment: I don't like this because it'll overwrite any other styles you apply to the element.

Comment: agree..didn't think of that

Comment: @CodeMonkey of course it will work, but just be aware of that if you want to just change one of multiple styles applied to an element.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to set an attribute of the element, not its style. To change the style, you do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("sharebar").style.width = "0px"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("sharebar").style.width = "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it is :

`document.getElementById("sharebar").style.width = "0px";`

for element that have - like z-index try the following :

`document.getElementById("sharebar").style.zIndex = "10";`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove styles:

```
document.getElementById("sharebar").style.width = null;
```

or if you only care about supporting IE9+

```
document.getElementById("sharebar").style.removeProperty('width');
```